# Mensagem de erro: "unfortunately has stopped eclipse"

Tags: android

Estou tentando criar um projeto android, porem está ocorrendo este erro quando executo a aplicação, "unfortunately has stopped eclipse", este o xml da aplicação:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="com.example.teste.MainActivity" >

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Coloca mais detalhes do erro.

Comment: Sim, essa não pode ser a mensagem literal do erro pois significa algo como "A falta de sorte parou o eclipse".

Comment: O problema é este, não da nenhum tipo de erro, o logcat esta vazio, o unico erro que acontece é este. Isto aconteceu quando baixei o ADT mais recente 23.6

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser muita coisa, no entanto, esse android:orientation está aí a mais isso é mais para a LinearLayout. Mas claro que não é suposto fazer crashar o Eclipse. Ás vezes mais vale peder 20 min e fazer um fresh install do que andar de volta desses erros misteriosos que acontecem depois das atualizações dos plugins. Acho que um erro desses não vêm só, e já basta os bugs que criamos sozinhos não precisamos de bugs da IDE ;)

Comment: IDEs tem sentimentos cara ._. (O Eclipse mais que todos).

Comment: Eu sei que sim eheh, digo que se reinstalarmos ficamos-nos a dar melhor com ele.